# How to add CSS to a HTML div which has no class or id

Tags: html, css

I have a WordPress plugin which creates an output like this:

```
<div>[Some Content]</div>
<div>[Some Content]</div>
<div>[Some Content]</div>
<div>[Some Content]</div>
<div>[Some Content]</div>
<div>[Some Content]</div>
```

All those div's have width:50% and a float:left; So I always have two in a row.

Now I need one div to be at 100% width.

How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: Where you want that div?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `nth-of-type()` selector to target a particular div. But you should have some parent element.

```
#parentid div:nth-of-type(2)
{
  background:#ff0000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works very good. I didnt know that there is anything like that.

Comment: thanks for the fiddle @Jared Farrish. You are welcome Konter.